# Clonezilla/DRBL and UEFI

Tags: uefi, clonezilla, pxe

I have been unable to PXE boot into Clonezilla/DRBL while in UEFI mode on a HP Notebook 15-ac180ca. While in Legacy mode I can boot into Clonezilla/DRBL (as long as I manually press the F12 (network boot) button. I, am, however, trying to do the network boot with UEFI enabled. Here is what I have done so far:

1. Installed Ubuntu 16.10 on the imaging server (we do not want to use a live CD)
2. As I only have one network card I removed network manager set up an virtual connection as eno1:0
3. Added "deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/drbl-core drbl stable" to the repository
4. Installed drbl/clonezilla using apt
5. I ran drblsrv -i and drblpush -i (for some reason each time I run this it creates a new user account on the imaging server with an account name which is a combination of the prefix name I specified and an ip address. If anyone knows why please let me know).
6. I ran dcs and started clonezilla

On the client, I boot up the machine. It initially connects over PXE boot. It says it successfully downloaded the NBP file. But then goes right into booting the OS on the client instead.

I read somewhere that I needed to modify the PATH in /tftpboot/nbi_img/pxelinux.cfg/default from bios/ to efi64/ I have done this, but it still does not seem to work.

What else do I need to do to get this to work under UEFI mode?

**Additional Info:**

This is what I see before it tries IPv6 and then proceeds to load the client OS:

```
>>Start PXE over IPv4, Press[ESC] to EXIT...
  Station IP address is 192.168.100.14

  Server IP address is 192.168.100.200
  NBP filename is bootx64.efi
  NBP filesize is 1019904 Bytes
 Downloading NBP file...

 Succeed to download NBP file
```

Comment: To my knowlege Clonezilla does not have the capability to support UEFI mode.

Comment: This page seems to indicate UEFI support. However, it is a bit cryptic to me...http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable